# nginx rewrite as special character in the parameter name

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Say I have a origin url `/example-url/endpoint?lang-code=something` needs to be rewritten as `/example-url/anther_endpoint?lang_code=something`.

and the rule like `rewrite ^/example-url/endpoint /example-url/anther_endpoint?lang_code=$arg_lang-code permanent` won't work, because hyper(`-`) is a special character,

So can this be archived by nginx?

Comment: Please show the full nginx configuration printed by `nginx -T`.

Comment: `rewrite` will automatically append the query string `?lang-code=something` to the rewritten URL - you do not need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: @RichardSmith it will be the `lang-code`, not the `lang_code`, the thing is as in RFC3986, `-` is a unreserved character.

Comment: Every character that is not a reserved character is an unreserved character including both `-` and `_`. However, Nginx does not form argument variables from parameter names containing hyphen. You will need to use `$args` or `$request_uri` to change `-` to `_`. Use a `map` or an `if` statement.